# Date Range Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am using [dangrossman daterangepicker](https://github.com/dangrossman/bootstrap-daterangepicker) in a site here is the code.

```
$('#reportrange').daterangepicker(
    {
      ranges: {
       //My added value
          'New Value':['This is just string value'],
          'Today': [moment(), moment()],
         'Yesterday': [moment().subtract('days', 1), moment().subtract('days', 1)],
         'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract('days', 6), moment()],
         'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract('days', 29), moment()],
         'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
         'Last Month': [moment().subtract('month', 1).startOf('month'), moment().subtract('month', 1).endOf('month')]
      },
      startDate: moment().subtract('days', 6),
      endDate: moment()
    },
    function(start, end) {
        $('#reportrange span').html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));
    }
);
```

[JsFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/umairorana/WQQR8/2/)

I just want in that list the ranges options will work as they are working but adding one more option here with the name of 'Newvalue' for this option I just want when user select this, string will be written in this div .

The error I am seeing is invalid date the ranges value is an array. I have tried this with double qoute single qoute values and with two values but it is not working. You can see its Fiddle.

Comment: Why would you want to add a string value in a `date range picker`. You have to specify date ranges as values

Comment: I am working on a site like this [Website Link](http://demo.improvely.com/reports/membershipsite/ads?tab=name&filters[ad]=1&filters[name]=Google%20AdWords&imt=1&utm_campaign=Site+Ads&utm_source=Date+Range+Picker&utm_medium=Banner&utm_content=GitHub+Demo+Image) You can see on the top right there is a date range picker I just want to add another option there which will do nothing displays the word New Value there.

Comment: Ugly hack: http://jsfiddle.net/WQQR8/11/ but I wouldn't consider that an answer to any problem, if you want to just add some label there modify the DOM and add a `<li>` element to the date range picking widget after the page is loaded, then attach some custom event handler - although that is ugly as well

Comment: Cool your ugly way is good ;) but what if I want to add one more text value here? Like you said in your code if the value is not a number in div than write "whatever text there"

Comment: You can do even more ugly hack: http://jsfiddle.net/WQQR8/13/ ;)

Comment: Appreciated ;) and what about the third value then you took it start and end actually there are total 3 values :D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66856/discussion-between-umair-rana-and-xjedam).

Answer (score 0):

You can use text box instead of div where you can either enter date manually or select date from options.

[jsfiddle Example1](http://jsfiddle.net/WQQR8/8/)

```
If you don't want to have this behaviour, then use this work around by hiding div nd showing text box for entering date.
```

[jsfiddle Example2](http://jsfiddle.net/WQQR8/10/)

Comment: I really appreciate for your efforts Example 2 is relevant but you can see initially New Value is in the dropdown but when you click on it the text New Value must come at the place where it is written select date. However, when you click on New Value the dropdown options are changing too. For example you are clicking on today today's date will display on the select date place and yesterday and so on but for new value option I just want the text display there New Value.